# LSH - Binary matrix representation from shingles

Tags: python, pandas, n-gram, lsh

I have a large dataset of news articles, 48000 to be precise. I have made ngrams of each article where `n = 3`.
my ngrams look like this:

```
[[(tikro, enters, into), (enter, into, research), (into, research, and),...]]
```

now I need to make a binary matrix of each shingle and article:

```
          article1 article2 article3
shingle1     1        0        0
shingle2     1        0        1
shingle3     0        1        0
```

At first I have kept all the shingles in a single list. After that, I have tried this to check if it works.

```
for art in article:
    for sh in ngrams:
        if sh in art:
            print('found')
```

as one is set and another is string it does not work. any suggestions, how to make it work? or any other approach?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before searching shingles in articles you could use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) to concatenate words of a shingle into a 3-word-phrase.

For example we have ngrams like:

```
ngrams = [('tikro', 'enters', 'into'),
          ('enter', 'into', 'research'),
          ('into', 'research', 'and')]
```

Then we concatenate words into phrase for each shingle:

```
shingles = [' '.join(x) for x in ngrams]
```

After the transformation the `shingles` is something like:

```
['tikro enters into', 
 'enter into research', 
 'into research and']
```

which are strings you could search in your articles.

Comment: Thank you a lot! it works smoothly. sorry that i did not reply earlier.

Comment: My pleasure to help you!